# How to add some Text before {controller}/{action}/{id} asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to change this

> localhosht:3220/MyController/MyAction?id=1

to this

> localhosht:3220/myText/MyController/MyAction?id=1

So that it works any time, even in redirection, routing or other cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the text to the route url:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "myText/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom `route` to match your desired `uri`. In the `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig`, add the following.

The order is important here, if you add the "Default" route before the "MyText" route, then *MyText* route will not be hit.

```
//for your custom route that starts with "myText"
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyText",
    url: "myText/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

//for other normal routes
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding a route with the `url` parameter of `myText/{controller}/{action}/{id}` (**above** your default route) will certainly work, if your intention is to use the `myText` frequently, you might also want to take a look at the concept of [areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx).

By default, in your `Global.asax`, in your `Application_Start()` function, you have a call for the method:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

What this does is to look for a special `Areas` folder in your project, and register each folder under it that has a class that extends from `AreaRegistration` and overrides the `RegisterArea` function. Similar to your `RouteConfig.cs`, this class can look like this:

```
public class MyTextAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyText";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "MyText_default",
            url: "MyText/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

note: you can create Areas in your MVC project by *scaffolding*: Just right click on your project and `Add..` -> `Area`. Everything will be done for you automatically.

In the end, Areas provide a more permanent solution to your `MyText/SomeController/SomeAction` needs. For a detailed article, you can check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC).

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{myText}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
defaults: new {
controller = "Home",
action = "Index",
id = UrlParameter.Optional,
myText= UrlParameter.Optional
```

);

It will work for you if you want to use parameter like myText to make your Url Seo friendly.